# Making links from script in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I want to make some links in my spreadsheet. I can make a string that looks like this. I looked around, though I did only find methods to link links that are already in the spreadsheet.

```
var linkBattlenet = "http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/"+toonrealm+"/"+toon.name+"/advanced"
var showLink = "battle.net link"+toon.name //this is what shall be seen in the spreadsheet.
```

I tried

```
 var showLink = "battle.net link"+toon.name
 var linkBattlenet = showLink.link("http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/"+toonrealm+"/"+toon.name+"/advanced")
```

Here i got the problem that it printed a string into the spreadsheet cell, that looks like this:

```
<a href="eu.battle.net---">"%Character name%" </a>.
```

(I am returnig the value in an array)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using showLink.link(), you can directly assign the string value to the cell.

Tried this code below:

```
function makeLink(){
  var name = "john";

var showLink = ""http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/+name+"/advanced"";
var mainsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Main');
  mainsheet.getActiveCell().setValue(showLink);

}
```

If you don't want to see the complete url in the cell, you can also try this line instead:

```
var showLink = '=HYPERLINK("http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/'+name+'/advanced","clickhere")';
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for reply. I tried the last option for you, whitch was what i was looking for. Thow i did not get the link in the spreadsheet. [link](http://gyazo.com/3dae4833c0a543136bb3514b5cfcbe2f) you see the Google spreadsheet did not prosess the hyperlink. I got my hole code (with the var showLink at line 650) as the reason i want it like this. [link] (http://pastebin.com/XAFTxzLE)

Comment: Check if the hyperlink posted in the sheet has ' ' around it. If it does, there is something wrong with the code that runs this. What is the script that uses this pull function? Also if you give us an example of Name+realm, that would help a lot.

Comment: the link to the picture is a complete picture inside google docs, there are no ' ' around it. you can use meltinglava ass toon.name and outland for toon,realm. link for my api would be [API link](http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/character/outland/Meltinglava?fields=) 
(which is where i get the JSON) and my link will be to [Character link](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/outland/Meltinglava/advanced)

Comment: The pull function is used inside google docs. the bottom retunt array returns the values into the doc. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vo5drEiTz7IhIzHJ0kTIeGJMZA1vWlNKQIvD_Qs-kUw/edit?usp=sharing is the link to my docs and it the C collom is where the pull function is used